# Automatically hide Google search results incuding specific keywords?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, google-search

I was searching something like "xxx algorithm interview question list" on Google, but then there's a lot of stupid things showing up in the results:

like "Interview...feel nervous speaking, and my thoughts turned blank whenever I was asked a xxx algorithm question."

I have no time for this. I know I could add things like -nervous -anxiety etc in the search query, but is there a permanent way (Stylish, Greasemonkey, extensions etc?) to remove Google search results that contain certain words??